# Mouse over functionality is not working when executing automation suite through Release Management

Tags: c#, selenium, continuous-integration, mouseover

I have developed an automation suite using Selenium and C#. This suite is also integrated with MTM. When i execute the suite through MTM Mouse over functionality is working properly, but when i am trying to execute the same through Release Management ( continuous Integration ) then it is not working.

Can anyone help me where exactly the issue is?

Thanks,
Phanindra

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a virtual screen? if yes check if the resolution of the virtual screen. You can verify it by taking a screenshot at the particular step when it is not performing the intended action.